# conflict python3.5 pycairo

Tags: python, igraph, cairo, pycairo

I everyone,

I am trying to install the cairo library for python, in order to use it for python-igraph.
My system mounts an Ubuntu Trusty distribution.
I have anaconda bundle with python3.5 as default.

The problem arises when I try to install pycairo:

`conda search pycairo`

it finds pycairo-1.10.0, which, according to Cairo website https://cairographics.org/pycairo/ should be precisely the one for python3.x
but when I try to install it, I get the message:

`The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pycairo
  - python 3.5*`

does this mean that there is no pycairo package for python3.5 ?